# Is it possible to save settings and load resources when compiling to just one standalone exe?

Tags: autohotkey

If I compile a script for distribution as a standalone exe, is there any way I can store settings within the exe itself, to save having to write to an external file? The main incentive for this is to save having to develop an installation process. I only need to store a few bytes.

Also, can resources such as images be compiled into the exe?

Comment: You can try saving it into Windows alternate streams for that exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Using alternate data streams opens up a can of worms so i wouldn't go that way. Writing back config data into the exe itself won't work as the file is locked for write access during execution.

What i usually do is to store config data under `%A_AppData%\%A_ScriptName%\%A_ScriptName%.ini`
When the script starts i use IniRead which also provides a default value if the key isn't found - which is the case the script is executing for the first time.
The complementing IniWrite's in a OnExit subroutine/function will create the ini file if necessary.
This way no installation is needed and the config is stored in the proper, familiar place.

Answer (score 0):

The `autohotkey` forum has dealt with this question before.
In that case, the user didn't want extra files -- period.

The method was to use the file system to save alternate data.
Unfortunately I can't find the post.

A simpler method is to use `fileinstall` command.
When the script is compiled, the external file is stored within the exe.

When the script executes the same command as an exe, the file is copied to the same
directory as the running script. It is a simple yet effective 'install'.
With a little testing for the config file, the `fileinstall` command can be skipped.

Skipping the `fileinstall` could allow changes to be made to the configuration after 'installation'

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried saving settings within the compiled exe file, but I have included resources. I'm not sure which version of AHK you're using or how you are compiling, but I can right-click my scripts to compile. There's an option to compile with options, where you can include resources in your compiled exe.[Compile with options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUPdG.png)